# How much xp per hour is fishing rocktails at level 90 fishing?

Tags: runescape

How much xp per hour can I expect fishing rocktails at level 90 fishing on RuneScape?

Comment: "xp an hour" or "xp per hour" (not "and hour") and "rocktails" (not "rocktail's")

Comment: well at lvl 99 fishing i catch over the 300 mark so i get 500k a hr but its not that good money 600k if bad i get 1m a hr botting runecrafting :)

Comment: @Artemis you can suggest edits by clicking the edit button bellow the question, you also get rep if it's accepted!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a [Rocktail Fishing Guide](http://forum.tip.it/topic/247138-rocktail-fishing-guide/). The author, with 99 fishing and a granite lobster, was able to catch **between 110 and 141 rocktails per hour**.

Answer (score 1):

I know you get 380 xp per fish, but I don't know how many you can catch in an hour.  If you get one at least every thirty seconds, you get 45,600 xp in that hour.  If you can get 3 every minute (or one every 20 seconds), you get 68,400.  So, probably between those two numbers.

I get all of my runescape information from [Zybez.net](http://www.zybez.net/), but their fishing guide doesn't say much about fishing rocktails.

Answer (score 0):

Fishing Rocktails gives 40,000 Fishing experience an hour with level 90 Fishing, according to the [wiki](https://runescape.wiki/w/Raw_rocktail#:%7E:text=Fishing%20rocktails%20gives%20between%2040%2C000%20Fishing%20experience%20an%20hour%2C%20with%20level%2090%20Fishing).

If you have 99 Fishing, it gives 45,000 xp per hour instead.

Note that however, fishing Rocktails for experience is no longer the best method; the highest experience per hour is now [Fishing Frenzy](https://runescape.wiki/w/Pay-to-play_Fishing_training#:%7E:text=94%2D99%2B-,Fishing%20Frenzy,-Over%20285%2C000%20experience), which gives over 285,000 experience per hour at 99 Fishing.